# Chrome extension localStorage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm developing a Google Chrome extension and I'm also using localstorage. I'm attempting to use the value that I get from the localstorage but all I can get is an `undefined`. How can I use the received value from the localstorage?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Given the accepted answer, this is probably a duplicate of: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: Hey just an FYI if you see [an existing question with the same question title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136870/chrome-extension-storage) as you, the solution is NOT to just misspell one of the words in your question title... It is a sign to make it clearer or more specific.

Comment: @aug, The accepted answer, and comment by the OP, clearly indicates this question is *not* actually about [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).  The acceptance of the provided answer indicates this is about [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Comment: @Makyen didn't see the accepted answer -- it just came up in the queue when reviewing so my bad but in either case my comment still stands except it should've been marked as a duplicate

Comment: @aug, no big deal. It's closed. My comment was about your edit, not your comment. I agree with your comment . Edit: I understand editing `localStorage` into the title instead of the "sotrage", as LS is repeated multiple times in the question. Unfortunately, in this case, it resulted in the question moving further away from what the acceptance of the answer *implies* the question is really about. It all comes down to the question just not being clear. Having a MCVE would have help clear things up. BTW: Feel free to downvote and/or vote to close when the question is unclear, a duplicate, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!

Assuming that you're using `chrome.storage`, the problem you're getting is because the "getting" from `chrome.storage` is asynchronous.
A way to solve this is using `promises`.

Like the example below:

```
highlightColor = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    chrome.storage.local.get("color", function (item) {
        resolve(item);
    });
});
```

Then, when the promise is ready, you can use its value like:

```
highlightColor.then(function (item) {
    if(item.color) {
        $(".jscolor").val(item.color);
    }
});
```

You can read more about `promises` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). If you want to check a project where I'm using `promises` and localStore you can check [this](https://github.com/rafaelcpalmeida/Word-Highlighter) repo.

Comment: Finally works! Thank you :)

Comment: @Dragon21 you're welcome. Happy coding

Comment: If you believed this was the answer to the question, then you should have flagged the question as a duplicate instead of answering.

Comment: @Makyen I'll keep that in mind the next time. Thanks for the piece of advice

Comment: There is a big difference between [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). Your answer confuses the two. Even though it is not clear from the question which of the two is actually being asked about, you should not confuse the two in your answer. Note: `localStorage` is *not* asynchronous.

Comment: @Makyen I'll update my answer. I confused `localStorage` with `chrome.storage`. `chrome.storage` is the one that is asynchronous.